# One way binding object in angular 2

Tags: angular, binding

How to achieve one-way binding in angular 2,  when you are repeating the array of the object and when you try to create on fly creation of the new object with predefined values.

I am getting the problem when user duplicate the object with predefine values the value enter in the both the object are becoming two binding.

```js
this.arraylist=[{id:"0", name:"some name"}];

function add(){

let obj1= {id:"0", name:"some name"}

arraylist.push(obj1);

}

// when arraylist repeat with object values as model to input textbox all the inputbox model values are becoming two way binded.
```

Comment: Please post your template code.

Comment: html please? It's a bit hard to figure out what you mean.

Answer (score 1):

when you push an predefine obj into array, you are just set `instance` of the object to the array. That why when you edit one and both of them are changed.

you can use `{...obj}` from `ES6`, this will copy the existing object with a new instance.

```
arraylist.push({...obj1});
```

you can confirm with this [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/MOmTtpn3txIYWlhZA8D2?p=preview).

Answer (score 1):

Here issue is we directly add `obj1` to `this.arraylist`.
Yo will have to make sure adding **copy** of `obj1` to `this.arraylist`.

1. ES6 has introduced Spread Operator("`...`") which can be used to create copy of obj which are are pushing to array.
2. ES6 has introduced `Object.assign({}, srcObj)` to create copy.

**Example is attached below**

```
var arr = [1, 2, 3];
var arr2 = [...arr]; // like arr.slice()
arr2.push(4); 

// arr2 becomes [1, 2, 3, 4]
// arr remains unaffected
```

**Your code correction is attached below**

**Way 1:**

```
arraylist.push({...obj1});
```

**Way 2:**

```
let copyObj = Object.assign({}, this.item);
this.data.push(copyObj);
```

Note: There are other techniques also to make copy of an object in JavaScript.

Cheers!